# How to stretch an image with code to a quadrilateral?

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic

If I have an square image, with the x-y coordinates of the 4 corners, and then a quadrilateral with the x-y coordinates of the 4 corners, how can I know what pixel color is each pixel of the quadrilateral? I basically want to stretch the original square to the quad.

Thanks, Is there an algorithm for this?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is called interpolation, and you basically work out the algebraic transformation of coordinates from your image to your quad.
Then use the inverse of this transformation to find for each quad pixel, where in the image it should map to.  This needn't be a whole number, so you'd have to use some kind of filtering (nearest neighbor, or bilinear, or other)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

Example:

```
Image 256x256
Map to coords   100,100 - 400,300
xout = x * ((400-100)/256) + 100
yout = y * ((300-100)/256) + 100
```

Comment: Also referred to as texture mapping or uv mapping (as the 2d images coords are typically referred to as u,v to avoid confusing them with the x,y coords for the destination).